# Dell Touchpad stop working

Tags: touchpad, dell-inspiron

I have a Dell Inspirion and I have these problems:

1- My buttons just don't work at all;

2- When I try to click with the touchpad it click as the right buttom instead of left and make a simple click/selection.

Obs:

1 - I already went in Control Panel> Mouse > Uncheck the "Change left-right button"
2 - I already tried to configure it by the dell's manager app;

PS: The only way the touchpad click works as it should be is when I insert an external USB mouse. Then it starts to work.

Please, some help!

Comment: Have you tried a clean installation of your touchpad drivers?

Comment: @slow_excellence Yes, I just formatted the notebook and installed the latest drivers =\\